# Errno 13 Permission Denied Keras VGG16

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, vgg-net

I'm trying to load the VGG16 model from Keras to perform transfer learning,

```
input_shape = (224, 224, 3)
model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=input_shape)
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-27-898653ab5324>", line 1, in <module>
    model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

  File "C:\Users\jywlj\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\applications\__init__.py", line 49, in wrapper
    return base_fun(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\jywlj\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\applications\vgg16.py", line 32, in VGG16
    return vgg16.VGG16(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\jywlj\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\keras_applications\vgg16.py", line 209, in VGG16
    file_hash='6d6bbae143d832006294945121d1f1fc')

  File "C:\Users\jywlj\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 223, in get_file
    if not validate_file(fpath, file_hash, algorithm=hash_algorithm):

  File "C:\Users\jywlj\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 324, in validate_file
    if str(_hash_file(fpath, hasher, chunk_size)) == str(file_hash):

  File "C:\Users\jywlj\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 299, in _hash_file
    for chunk in iter(lambda: fpath_file.read(chunk_size), b''):

  File "C:\Users\jywlj\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 299, in <lambda>
    for chunk in iter(lambda: fpath_file.read(chunk_size), b''):

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

This is really strange, as loading the VGG19 network gives me no problem. Also, if I remove the "include_top" argument, the model loads successfully without throwing the error.

```
# This works fine
model = VGG16(weights='imagenet')
```

Can anyone help with this? Thanks.

Comment: what is your input_shape?

Comment: I've tried both 224x224 and 128x128, both worked fine on the VGG19.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of importing from keras, you can import from tensorflow.

```py
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG16
```

This will solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm still getting the same error.